# Как на NodeJs определить MTU(длину одного пакета)?

Tags: node.js, mtu

Хотелось бы понять как на NodeJs можно определить длину пакета MTU? Возможно я не верно сформулировал, но суть такая, что как я понял длины пакетов разные для различных типов сетей(например GPON, LAN) а так же типов подключения к интернету pppoe VPN и так далее.
Как реализовывать для меня в данном случаи особого значения не имеет, при этом предпочтительнее для socket или HTTP или WebSocket(если конечно такое возможно).

Comment: Это больше баловство и желание понимать как. Вполне возможно что применение найдётся и другое. Сейчас идея в определении таким образом пользователей которые используют VPN поскольку у microsoft pptp своя длина пакета, как и у android который подключен по VPN(между собой они отличаются). То есть по факту получается, я узнал новую фишку и пока что хочу понять как ей реализовать. А смогу ли я использовать её в каком то серьёзном проекте - это уже время покажет.

Comment: Я знаю что wireshark это снифер, только пользовался я ранее им на Windows, на Linux опыта не было. При этом не понял как определить MTU через предлагаемый Вами nodeshark. Можете ли Вы привести пример кода на NodeJs для решения данной задачи?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что этот вопрос имеет мало отношения к [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)

MTU - это атрибут интерфейса. MTU может варьироваться по пути от источника к месту назначения. Так, например, линк от A до B может иметь MTU X, но линк от B до C может быть Y.

```
$ ifconfig  | grep mtu
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
EHC29: flags=0<> mtu 0
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
EHC26: flags=0<> mtu 0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
```

Возможно, вы сможете определить значение MTU некоторого канала связи, по которому прошел пакет, если увидите фрагментированные пакеты. Но я не дам готового решения для того, чтобы сделать это. Возьмите библиотеку [pcap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap) и исследуйте это.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/49812/18897) на вопрос "How to view MTU size in Wireshark?"</sub>

Comment: На 2ip.ru/privacy/ есть сервис который определяет MTU. Понятно что разные сетевые интерфейсы по мере прохождения пакета могут иметь разные MTU, при этом я думал что для сокета по которому установлена связь MTU будет постоянным исходя из минимальной длины или я не прав? Сервис ссылку на который я оставил например если я к сети Интернет подключаюсь через Wi-Fi который создаётся телефоном подключённым к Мегафон то MTU равен 1400. Если у Вас сервис не показал MTU, значит он стандартный для локалки.